# CUDA event Error on matrix addition

Tags: cuda

I encountered a problem that I do not know how to solve it, Can you help me if possible.

I want to measure the execution time of addition of two 1D arrays,
So i try to implements and execute the kernel on my GF820 M, the results of the addition kernel (I put them in a file) are correct but timing values of executin obtained by this kernel are very low which I questioned for these values if there are correct or not.

I figured that the problem is in the instructions execution time measurements but I followed the same syntax exists in CUDA programing guide.

the execution is done on GF 820 M :

for WIDTH=20480 and Number of threads=512 ; the time=0,01812 ms

and for WIDTH=20480 and Number of threads=1024 ; the time=0,021920 ms

thank you in advance for any help you might be able to provide.

the code :

```
  __global__ void kernel_sum(float *x, float *y, float *z, int size) {
      int gtid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
        z[gtid] = x[gtid] + y[gtid];
        }

 int main ()

{           
          cudaError_t cudaStatus;
          float *array1_d , *array2_d ,*M_result_array_d ; // device array
          const int WIDTH=20480 ;

          float  *array1_h = (float *)malloc(WIDTH*sizeof(float));
          float  *array2_h= (float*)malloc(WIDTH*sizeof(float));
          float  *M_result_array_h = (float *)malloc(WIDTH*sizeof(float));

        //remplissage des deux matrices d'entree

       for ( int i = 0 ; i<WIDTH; i++ ) 
                             {  array1_h[i]=i; 
                               array2_h[i]=i; }                         

      // Allocate GPU buffers for 2 matrices (two input, one output) 
        cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **) &array1_d , WIDTH*sizeof (float));
   if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) { fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!"); }  

        cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **) &array2_d , WIDTH*sizeof (float));
   if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) { fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!"); }  

     //allocating memory for resultent device array
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void **) &M_result_array_d , WIDTH*sizeof   (float) ) ;
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!"); } 

   //copy host array to device array;
cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy ( array1_d , array1_h , WIDTH*sizeof (float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) ;

 if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) { fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy 0 failed!"); }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy ( array2_d , array2_h,WIDTH*sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) ;
if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) { fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy 1 failed!"); }

           //lancer kernel
              const int t=512;
              int NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS = WIDTH/t;
              cudaEvent_t start, stop;
               float time;
               cudaEventCreate(&start);
               cudaEventCreate(&stop);
              cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
      kernel_sum <<<NUMBER_OF_BLOCKS,t>>> ( array1_d , array2_d ,M_result_array_d ,WIDTH) ;
              cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
              cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
              cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
              cudaEventDestroy(start);
              cudaEventDestroy(stop);

cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {fprintf(stderr, "Kernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus)); }

//afffichage de temps du kernel et enregister dans un fichier 
        printf ("N=%5d  NT=%5d Time=%5f \n",WIDTH,t,time);

//copy back result_array_d to result_array_h

 cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(M_result_array_h , M_result_array_d , WIDTH*sizeof(float) ,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) ;

    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) { fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy result from GPU to host failed!"); } 



    /*//print result

  printf("A \n");
  for ( int i = 0 ; i<WIDTH ; i++ )  
         { printf("%f  ", array1_h[i] );printf ("\n") ;
          } printf ("\n") ;
             printf ("\n");

 printf("B \n"); for ( int i = 0 ; i<WIDTH; i++ )  
          {  printf("%f  ", array2_h[i] );printf ("\n") ;
          } printf ("\n") ;
            printf ("\n");


  printf("Resultat \n");
  for (int i = 0 ; i<WIDTH ; i++ )
     {   printf ("%f   ",M_result_array_h[i] ) ;printf ("\n") ; }
      printf ("\n") ;  
       printf ("\n");

       */

    FILE* fichier = NULL;
    fichier = fopen("resultat.text", "a+");
            if (fichier != NULL)
                {   for (int i = 0 ; i<WIDTH ; i++ )
                    fprintf(fichier, "%5f \n ",M_result_array_h[i]);
                      fprintf(fichier, "\n ");      
                         fclose(fichier);
                                              } 
           else  {printf("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier"); }


    cudaFree(array1_d);
    cudaFree(array2_d);
    cudaFree(M_result_array_d);





  system("pause") ; 

}
```

Comment: I get 0.0208ms, pretty much the same as your time.  Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Could you please fix your code formatting. That code is extremely hard to read as posted

Comment: I found on the internet the code of the kernel and the execution time measures of this kernel on GTX 560 Ti. My problem is that when I execute the kernel on my GF 820M, the results of the addition (I put them in a file) are correct but the time values of executin for the same values of N taken by the kernel on the internet are very different.

Comment: while I found on the internet that the two architectures are of compute capability 2.1. this gives almost similar execution time and not altogether different. I just send you the site where I found the implementation and values. (part 3.3.1.b) adaptive solution with multiple blocks "http://www.info.univ-angers.fr/~richer/cuda_crs3. php ").

Comment: From the compute capability you cannot conclude on the performance. The GTX 560 Ti is a much faster GPU compared to your 820M. With which values from the link do you compare? Can you include that in your question?

Comment: on my GF 820M for WIDTH=20480 and Number of threads=1024 ; the time=0,021920 ms .while in the link (http://www.info.univ-angers.fr/~richer/cuda_crs3.php) Number threads=1024  and the times egal to 369.6 ms .

Comment: this means that GTX 560 Ti is not faster than my GF 820M, which is false.
that's why I think that the time measurements are incorrect for my code.

Comment: In the link the timings are for "10.000 itérations pour vecteur de taille 262.144 floats".

Comment: justly ,the size of 262,144 float is lower compared to 20480 float and provides a higher time (369.6) than the 20480.(0.021ms)

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Your vector size is a factor of 10 **smaller** compared to the link **and** the example in the link is executed 10.000 times. Which makes your problem a factor of 10^5 smaller and the timings look reasonable.

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: Does someone want to add a short answer to this question to get it off the unanswered list please?

Answer (score 1):

I think those times make sense. But if you really want to know the performance of your kernels, is better to use *nvprof* and *nvvp* than mesure time with *cudaEventElapsedTime*.

Here an execution in a Gforce Titan X with nvprof:

```
==20602== NVPROF is profiling process 20602, command: ./test
N=20480  NT=  512 Time=0.026720 
==20602== Profiling application: ./test
==20602== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
63.50%  19.648us         2  9.8240us  9.7920us  9.8560us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
28.75%  8.8960us         1  8.8960us  8.8960us  8.8960us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
 7.76%  2.4000us         1  2.4000us  2.4000us  2.4000us  kernel_sum(float*, float*, float*, int)

==20602== API calls:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
97.28%  156.96ms         3  52.321ms  3.1070us  156.95ms  cudaMalloc
 2.15%  3.4675ms       332  10.444us     180ns  437.61us  cuDeviceGetAttribute
 0.20%  317.27us         4  79.318us  79.038us  79.945us  cuDeviceTotalMem
 0.17%  270.27us         4  67.567us  64.960us  74.955us  cuDeviceGetName
 0.11%  171.56us         3  57.185us  4.4910us  142.25us  cudaFree
 0.07%  117.87us         3  39.288us  29.311us  57.825us  cudaMemcpy
 0.01%  20.980us         1  20.980us  20.980us  20.980us  cudaLaunch
 0.00%  5.6630us         1  5.6630us  5.6630us  5.6630us  cudaEventSynchronize
 0.00%  5.1940us         2  2.5970us  2.2760us  2.9180us  cudaEventRecord
 0.00%  3.1650us         2  1.5820us     542ns  2.6230us  cudaEventCreate
 0.00%  3.0440us         4     761ns     167ns  2.3220us  cudaSetupArgument
 0.00%  2.6610us         8     332ns     204ns     619ns  cuDeviceGet
 0.00%  1.8210us         1  1.8210us  1.8210us  1.8210us  cudaEventElapsedTime
 0.00%  1.7800us         2     890ns     510ns  1.2700us  cudaEventDestroy
 0.00%  1.3870us         2     693ns     338ns  1.0490us  cuDeviceGetCount
 0.00%  1.2160us         1  1.2160us  1.2160us  1.2160us  cudaConfigureCall
 0.00%     339ns         1     339ns     339ns     339ns  cudaGetLastError
```